# aarch64 Exception Level Switch from EL1 to EL0

Tags: exception, switch-statement, arm64

I am working on a simple kernel and test it on Qemu which supports RasPi3.

During the boot level, Ras Pi goes to EL3 level, and I set spsr_el3 to 1 and elr_el3 to kernel_main and then use eret to enter EL1 mode.

My problem is: I create a kernel thread which still in EL1 level. I want to switch the kernel thread to user level.

What I did is that this kernel thread also set spsr_el1 to 0 and elr_el1 to a function pointer, then eret. But this case a sync interrupt, I think caused by this eret?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can provide an answer to your problem.

Comment: Reformat text and remove "need help"

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am facing a similar issue on switching from EL1 to EL0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the Exception Syndrome Register, ESR_EL1 or ESR_EL3, but you will also have to figure out whether your are taking your exception to EL1 or EL3.  There are reasons it could be either.